# Dismissing menu if tap anywhere else on the screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, github, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I'm using this [Menu](https://github.com/feiin/DWBubbleMenuButton.Swift) from github. Currently the menu opens on tap and  retracts if you click the tap button again, but I also want the menu to retract if the user taps anywhere else on the screen except the buttons. The problem I'm running into is that I am implementing this in navbar with tabbarcontroller, what happens is that if i tap the button to open the menu and then click on the different tab without collapsing the bubble menu. And then if I come back to the same tab, the bubble menu is visually still open but in code it still thinks it is collapsed, that leads to weird behavior of adding another subview any suggestions?

The following is the example of how it works now.  And here is the [link to the Code.](https://github.com/feiin/DWBubbleMenuButton.Swift/blob/master/source/DWBubbleMenuButton.swift) 
[image]

Comment: I see in the source code there's a  function named "dismissbuttons". Maybe you want to call it in appropriate time.

Comment: I went through that as well.  I just don't know how to detect a outside touch so i can call the dismissbuttons function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 approaches:

## First approach:

You can set a tag for your buttons and other views that you don't want the menu to be dismissed when they get tapped:

```
button.tag=99;
button2.tag=99;
backgroundImage.tag=99;
```

And then in your viewcontroller, use the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` delegate

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.view.tag!=99){
        //Call your dismiss method
    }

}
```

## Second approach:

If there's an overlay for your buttons (e.g. the background to highlight your buttons, and fill all over your view) , you can add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it, and add it to your view every time you want your custom view to show up. Here's an example:

```
UIView *overlay;

-(void)addOverlay{
    //Add the overlay, if there's one in your code, then you don't have to create this
        overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];

    //Register the tap gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *overlayTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(onOverlayTapped)];

    [overlay addGestureRecognizer:overlayTap];

    [self.view addSubview:overlay];
}


- (void)onOverlayTapped
{
   //Call your dismiss method

    for (UITapGestureRecognizer *ges in previewOverlay.gestureRecognizers) {
        [overlay removeGestureRecognizer:ges];
    }
    [overlay removeFromSuperview];

}
```

You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32151408/2655063) here for a similar case.

Comment: I am now able to detect the overlay tapped and print a message on the console, however I tried to call the  dismissbuttons method like so: DWBubbleMenuButton().dismissButtons()   and nothing happens

Comment: well, it's beyond of this question's scope but I think you should do a separate test where you only want to dismiss the buttons by any way possible. Once you done that, then try to combine them into one.

Comment: Beauty of being a newbie, running into a problem now after the menu is dismissed the clear overlay still has interaction and won't allow any interaction with the view controller

Comment: after dismissing your buttons, you have to remove the the overlay from super view as well (or it will block your interaction). Also, you may want to remove all of the gesture recognizers from the overlay before doing that to make sure things are going right. That's why I put overlay as a global variable. I've updated the code to give you a hint to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
         super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
         //retract menu
}
```

This function detects a background tap.

Comment: Do i call this in view controller I'm using the menu in? and how would i differentiate the touch of menu buttons from rest of the view controller screen

Answer (score 1):

I used FlysoFast code and converted it to Swift, to detect an outside tap:

```
self.overlay = UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
downMenuButton.delegate = self
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("bubbleMenuButtonShouldCollapse"))

tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.overlay.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
self.overlay.addSubview(downMenuButton)
self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(overlay)
```

Then I used the following code:

```
func bubbleMenuButtonShouldCollapse() {
   println("Overlay tapped")
   self.downMenuButton.dismissButtons()
}
```

to collapse the menu.